# rspec model test uniqueness

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

What would be the proper syntax for testing with rails 4 after the depreciation of `validates_uniqueness_of`?

in my model...

```
# prior to Rails 4
validates_uniqueness_of :number

# Rails 4
validates :number, uniqueness: true
```

in my test file...

```
# prior to rails 4
it {should validate_uniqueness_of(:number)}
```

this test fails...

```
# this fails but with the correct error message expected
it "validates the uniqueness of number" do
  Fabricate(:wo, number: "494949")
  expect{Fabricate.build(:wo, number: "494949")}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, "Validation failed: Number has already been taken")
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I love thoughtbot's `shoulda-matchers` gem.  Once you install, there are one liner tests you can include for most of your model setup, including uniqueness (validate_uniqueness_of).

Comment: i thought that `validates_uniqueness_of`is now depreciated in rails 4

Comment: True (I think) for the model as you say in your post, but the gem gives you a nice matcher.  I run 4.2 and in my test I have:  `it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }`.

Comment: You could also change `to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, "Validation failed: Number has already been taken")` to `should_not be_valid`.  When it fails, what is the output you get?  If you still have doubts, maybe update your post with the test output in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `build` won't actually run the validations. Try `Fabricate(:wo, number: "494949")`.